# When I was using google place api, I got an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, but I only sent 3 times in last 24 hours

Tags: android, google-api, google-places-api

I'm using google place api to develop a mobile application.

The Http request I sent was:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?sensor=true&key=KEY&components=country:uk&input=hu

But when I sent HTTP request to the Google server, it replies OVER_QUERY_LIMIT:
{
   "predictions" : [],
   "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}

I have checked the instruction provided by Google and Android document, and also I have checked the usage of the requests from reports in the Google Console. But I found the used request is only 3, and the request/sec is 0.0017.

Could anyone provide some help on it? Thanks very much!

Comment: please post the code that you have implement for your place api.

Comment: @Ankxx13 Hi, thanks for replying. But, is it an issue on the code? Even i pasted the url to the browser, I still got the same status.

Answer (score 0):

Oh...I have fixed up my error.

The reason was that I was using a public-shared API_Key by mistake, so sometimes I could get the result, but sometimes couldn't.